# Extracting list with multiple records with Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have a problem expanding data from json file with Power Query.
This is the basic structure received in json format:

```
{
  "data": {
    "assets": [
      {
        "asset": "apple",
        "metrics": [
          {
            "value": 2,
            "metric": "weight"
          },
          {
            "value": "red",
            "metric": "color"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "asset": "banana",
        "metrics": [
          {
            "value": "yellow",
            "metric": "color"
          },
          {
            "value": 3,
            "metric": "weight"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is how it looks like in PowerQuery:

| asset | details |
| --- | --- |
| apple | List |
| banana | List |

each list looks as follows:

| List |
| --- |
| Record |
| Record |
| Record |

each record inside list looks as follows:

| - | - |
| --- | --- |
| metricName | weight |
| value | 2 |

When I use "Extract Values" function on the "details" column in the first table I get *"Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Record to type Text."*, when I expand it to new rows it works but I end up with table like this (multiple rows for the same asset):

| asset | metricName | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | weight | 2 |
| apple | color | red |
| banana | weight | 3 |
| banana | color | yellow |

My expected result is this:

| asset | weight | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2 | red |
| banana | 3 | yellow |

Comment: Please post a copy of a sample JSON for us to work with by editing your question and pasting it in there along with a copy your existing code from home...advanced editor...  Otherwise we have nothing to work with to help you

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

| asset | metricName | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | weight | 2 |
| apple | color | red |
| banana | weight | 3 |
| banana | color | yellow |

I was expanding lists to get to the above table. Then with the above table I did the following:

- Pivoted it on "asset" and used "value" as Values Column,
- Demoted Headers,
- Transposed Table,
- Promoted Headers

... I and ended up with expected result.

Comment: why not share the code for others, and paste it in your answer